# Bundle node js code into one file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried using browserify etc...  But they include browser specific code.  I just want one javascript file to contain all my server side app.

I want to compile all the disparate sources of a server side node.js app into one file "app.js" so I can distribute it by itself and it contains all dependencies it requires inside the one file.

So if I had: 
one.js

```
require('./two.js')
```

two.js

```
console.log('two');
```

I'd run bundler one.js -o app.js

and app.js would look like:

```
console.log('two')
```

Ideally it would deal with the node system modules like fs, util, etc... intelligently.  (I.e. probably not bundle them.)

Answer (score 1):

Many nodejs modules require building or installation so you should consider distributing the `node_modules` folder or running `npm install` to install your app. If all the modules you use are simple js files with no further dependencies, I guess what you are looking for is to just merge the files together. You can easily do this with [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) (and `gulp-concat`).

```
 var gulp       = require('gulp'),         
     concat     = require('gulp-concat');

    gulp.src(['imustbefirst.js', 'imustbesecond.js', '*.js'])           
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))     
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
```